# Moving rectange using pygame keeps flickering

Tags: python, pygame

```
import pygame
import random

black  = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
green = (0,255,0)
red = (255,0,0)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1200, 600))
title = pygame.display.set_caption("Speeding cars")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
clock.tick(60)

class Car:
    def __init__(self, x, y, height, width):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.height = height
        self.width = width

    def drive(self, change):
        self.change = random.randint(1, 3)
        self.x += self.change
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, black, (self.x, self.y, self.height, self.width))
        pygame.display.flip()

car1 = Car(30, 100, 50, 15)
car2 = Car(30, 200, 50, 15)
car3 = Car(30, 300, 50, 15)
car4 = Car(30, 400, 50, 15)
car5 = Car(30, 500, 50, 15)

driving = True

while driving:

    screen.fill(white)

    car1.drive(0)
    car2.drive(0)
    car3.drive(0)
    car4.drive(0)
    car5.drive(0)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
        pygame.display.flip()
```

When i try to run this code everything works fine but the rectanges keeps flickering. I tried changing flip to update and  adding or removing `pygame.display.flip()` at different points in code but it dosent seem to work.
Edit: I also just realised that when i comment out the rest of the cars and only run the first one, it runs fine. The problem starts with the second car.
 Thanks for help.

Comment: I read only title and I will guess - you use `screen.fill()` or `pygame.display.flip()` in many places. You should use it only in one place.

Comment: you should use `pygame.display.flip()` only in `while driving` afer `for event`, not inside `for event` - you have wrong indentation in last line. And don't use it `drive()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of updating the screen in the `drive()` method, do it at the end of your main loop.

Also, try not to use repetitive code for each new object that is created, but use a for loop instead.

Here you go:

```
import pygame
import random

black  = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
green = (0,255,0)
red = (255,0,0)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1200, 600))
title = pygame.display.set_caption("Speeding cars")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
clock.tick(60)

class Car:
    def __init__(self, x, y, height, width):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.height = height
        self.width = width

    def drive(self, change):
        self.change = random.randint(1, 1)
        self.x += self.change
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, black, (self.x, self.y, self.height, self.width))

cars = []
for i in range(1,6):
    cars.append(Car(30, 100*i, 50, 15)) 

driving = True

while driving:

    screen.fill(white)

    for car in cars:
        car.drive(0)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()

    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 1):

There should be only one `flip()`/`update()` which is executed after you `draw` all shapes and `blit` all image. It sends buffer `screen` to video card which display it on monitor.

If you use after every `drive` then it send `screen` to monitor with only one car and later it send `screen` only with second car, etc.

```
import pygame
import random

black  = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
green = (0,255,0)
red = (255,0,0)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1200, 600))
title = pygame.display.set_caption("Speeding cars")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
clock.tick(60)

class Car:
    def __init__(self, x, y, height, width):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.height = height
        self.width = width

    def drive(self, change):
        self.change = random.randint(1, 3)
        self.x += self.change
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, black, (self.x, self.y, self.height, self.width))
        # pygame.display.flip() # don't use it

car1 = Car(30, 100, 50, 15)
car2 = Car(30, 200, 50, 15)
car3 = Car(30, 300, 50, 15)
car4 = Car(30, 400, 50, 15)
car5 = Car(30, 500, 50, 15)

driving = True

while driving:

    screen.fill(white)

    car1.drive(0)
    car2.drive(0)
    car3.drive(0)
    car4.drive(0)
    car5.drive(0)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()

    pygame.display.flip() # after `for event`, not inside `for event`
```